# How to convert one step checkout to multistep checkout in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, onepage-checkout

I want to convert one step to multi-step on the checkout page in one-page checkout.

It's working on step form on the same page.

Needs to convert multistep to different pages on the checkout page.

How to do this.

Comment: Did you find a way to convert one step to multistep?